# Vírgula em "e assim"

Tags: vírgula

Em qual frase está corretamente empregado o uso da vírgula em "e assim"?

1. Quando se trabalha em um grupo, nós nos abrimos para os movimentos que acontecem neste sistema **e, assim,** as dinâmicas são reveladas e compreendemos os nossos aprisionamentos e sofrimentos.
2. Quando se trabalha em um grupo, nós nos abrimos para os movimentos que acontecem neste sistema **e assim,** as dinâmicas são reveladas e compreendemos os nossos aprisionamentos e sofrimentos.

Imagino que a primeira frase esteja correta e a segunda esteja errada.

Imagino também que há uma outra forma de construir a frase:

3. Quando se trabalha em um grupo, nós nos abrimos para os movimentos que acontecem neste sistema, **e assim** as dinâmicas são reveladas e compreendemos os nossos aprisionamentos e sofrimentos.

É isso mesmo?

Answer (score 3):

Eu colocaria a vírgula antes da conjunção *e*. É local de pausa quando se lê a frase, e orações com sujeitos diferentes ligadas por *e*, como é o caso, tendem ainda mais a ser separadas por vírgula.

Na Gramática de Bechara, temos:

> Vírgula – Emprega-se a vírgula:
>   a) [...]
>   b) para separar orações coordenadas aditivas ainda que sejam iniciadas pela conjunção *e*, proferidas com pausa.

Se a frase fosse diferente, sem *assim* a introduzir um valor mais conclusivo do que meramente aditivo, a ausência da vírgula seria em minha opinião mais aceitável:

> Quando trabalhamos em grupo, abrimo-nos para os movimentos que acontecem nesse sistema e as dinâmicas são reveladas.

Quanto a *assim*, este pode estar entre vírgulas (como em geral estão os adjuntos adverbiais que precedem o verbo) ou não, dependendo do realce que se lhe quiser dar. Na gramática de Cunha e Cintra temos (citações internas omitidas):

> [A] vírgula é usada: [...]
>   d) para isolar o adjunto adverbial antecipado: [...]
>
> **Observação**:
>
> Quando os adjuntos adverbiais são de pequeno corpo (um advérbio, por exemplo), costuma-se dispensar a vírgula. A vírgula é, porém, de regra quando se pretende realçá-los. Comparem-se estes passos:
>
> > Depois levaram Ricardo para a casa da mãe Avelina.
> >     Depois, o engraçado são as passagens de nível, os aparelhos de sinalização, os vagões-cisternas…
> >     Depois, tudo caiu em silêncio.

A frase tem outros aspetos que considero talvez um pouco infelizes, como repetir *e* pouco depois e começar com uma construção impessoal com *se* para depois mudar para a primeira pessoa.